# Can't do any updates after upgrade to Centos 8

Tags: update, centos8, dnf

```
[_admin_@wb_centos ~]$ sudo dnf upgrade
CentOS Linux 8 - BaseOS                         0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:00    
CentOS Linux 8 - AppStream                      0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:00    
Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'baseos', ignoring this repo.
Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'appstream', ignoring this repo.
Last metadata expiration check: 0:26:15 ago on Sun 17 Jul 2022 11:24:13 PM CDT.
Module yaml error: Unexpected key in data
Module defaults error: Unexpected key in data
Dependencies resolved.

 Problem 1: cannot install the best update candidate for package aalib-libs-1.4.0-0.22.rc5.el7.x86_64
  - nothing provides libtinfo.so.6()(64bit) needed by aalib-libs-1.4.0-0.37.rc5.el8.x86_64
  - nothing provides libncurses.so.6()(64bit) needed by aalib-libs-1.4.0-0.37.rc5.el8.x86_64
 Problem 2: cannot install the best update candidate for package elrepo-release-7.0-5.el7.elrepo.noarch
  - nothing provides glibc = 2.28 needed by elrepo-release-8.1-1.el8.elrepo.noarch
 Problem 3: cannot install the best update candidate for package game-music-emu-0.6.2-1.el7.x86_64
  - nothing provides libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.9)(64bit) needed by game-music-emu-0.6.2-3.el8.x86_64
 Problem 4: cannot install the best update candidate for package gperftools-libs-2.6.1-1.el7.x86_64
  - nothing provides libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.9)(64bit) needed by gperftools-libs-1:2.7-9.el8.x86_64
  - nothing provides libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.8)(64bit) needed by gperftools-libs-1:2.7-9.el8.x86_64
  - nothing provides libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.27)(64bit) needed by gperftools-libs-1:2.7-9.el8.x86_64
 Problem 5: cannot install the best update candidate for package jack-audio-connection-kit-1.9.9.5-6.el7.x86_64
  - nothing provides libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.21)(64bit) needed by jack-audio-connection-kit-1.9.14-4.el8.x86_64
  - nothing provides libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.20)(64bit) needed by jack-audio-connection-kit-1.9.14-4.el8.x86_64
  - nothing provides libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.8)(64bit) needed by jack-audio-connection-kit-1.9.14-4.el8.x86_64
  - nothing provides libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.27)(64bit) needed by jack-audio-connection-kit-1.9.14-4.el8.x86_64
 Problem 6: cannot install the best update candidate for package libaom-3.1.1-1.el7.x86_64
  - nothing provides libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.27)(64bit) needed by libaom-3.1.1-1.el8.x86_64
 Problem 7: cannot install the best update candidate for package libcaca-0.99-0.40.beta20.el7.x86_64
  - nothing provides libtinfo.so.6()(64bit) needed by libcaca-0.99-0.59.beta20.el8.x86_64
  - nothing provides libncursesw.so.6()(64bit) needed by libcaca-0.99-0.59.beta20.el8.x86_64
 Problem 8: cannot install the best update candidate for package libcddb-1.3.2-12.el7.x86_64
  - nothing provides libcdio.so.18()(64bit) needed by libcddb-1.3.2-30.el8.x86_64
  - nothing provides libcdio.so.18(CDIO_18)(64bit) needed by libcddb-1.3.2-30.el8.x86_64
 Problem 9: cannot install the best update candidate for package libffado-2.1.0-4.el7.x86_64
  - nothing provides libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.21)(64bit) needed by libffado-2.4.4-2.el8.x86_64
  - nothing provides libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.20)(64bit) needed by libffado-2.4.4-2.el8.x86_64
 Problem 10: cannot install the best update candidate for package libmfx-1.21-2.el7.x86_64
  - nothing provides libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.9)(64bit) needed by libmfx-1.25-4.el8.x86_64
  - nothing provides libva-drm.so.2()(64bit) needed by libmfx-1.25-4.el8.x86_64
  - nothing provides libva-x11.so.2()(64bit) needed by libmfx-1.25-4.el8.x86_64
  - nothing provides libva.so.2()(64bit) needed by libmfx-1.25-4.el8.x86_64
 Problem 11: cannot install the best update candidate for package libmodplug-1:0.8.9.0-9.el7.x86_64
  - nothing provides libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.9)(64bit) needed by libmodplug-1:0.8.9.0-9.el8.x86_64
 Problem 12: cannot install the best update candidate for package libspatialaudio-3.1-1.20200406gitd926a2e.el7.x86_64
  - nothing provides libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.27)(64bit) needed by libspatialaudio-3.1-1.20200406gitd926a2e.el8.x86_64
 Problem 13: cannot install the best update candidate for package libssh2-1.8.0-4.el7.x86_64
  - nothing provides libcrypto.so.1.1()(64bit) needed by libssh2-1.9.0-5.el8.x86_64
  - nothing provides libcrypto.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_0)(64bit) needed by libssh2-1.9.0-5.el8.x86_64
  - nothing provides libssl.so.1.1()(64bit) needed by libssh2-1.9.0-5.el8.x86_64
  - nothing provides libcrypto.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_1)(64bit) needed by libssh2-1.9.0-5.el8.x86_64
 Problem 14: cannot install the best update candidate for package libxml++-2.37.1-1.el7.x86_64
  - nothing provides libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.9)(64bit) needed by libxml++-2.40.1-10.el8.x86_64
  - nothing provides libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.21)(64bit) needed by libxml++-2.40.1-10.el8.x86_64
 Problem 15: cannot install the best update candidate for package lirc-libs-0.10.0-16.el7.x86_64
  - nothing provides libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.20)(64bit) needed by lirc-libs-0.10.0-19.el8.x86_64
  - nothing provides libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.27)(64bit) needed by lirc-libs-0.10.0-19.el8.x86_64
 Problem 16: cannot install the best update candidate for package rpmconf-1.0.22-1.el7.noarch
  - nothing provides rpm-python3 needed by rpmconf-1.1.3-1.el8.noarch
 Problem 17: cannot install the best update candidate for package sox-14.4.1-7.el7.x86_64
  - nothing provides libpng16.so.16()(64bit) needed by sox-14.4.2.0-29.el8.x86_64
  - nothing provides libpng16.so.16(PNG16_0)(64bit) needed by sox-14.4.2.0-29.el8.x86_64
  - nothing provides libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.27)(64bit) needed by sox-14.4.2.0-29.el8.x86_64
 Problem 18: cannot install the best update candidate for package tcp_wrappers-7.6-77.el7.x86_64
  - nothing provides libnsl.so.2()(64bit) needed by tcp_wrappers-7.6-96.el8.x86_64
  - nothing provides libnsl.so.2(LIBNSL_1.0)(64bit) needed by tcp_wrappers-7.6-96.el8.x86_64
 Problem 19: cannot install the best update candidate for package tcp_wrappers-libs-7.6-77.el7.x86_64
  - nothing provides libnsl.so.2()(64bit) needed by tcp_wrappers-libs-7.6-96.el8.x86_64
  - nothing provides libnsl.so.2(LIBNSL_1.0)(64bit) needed by tcp_wrappers-libs-7.6-96.el8.x86_64
 Problem 20: cannot install the best update candidate for package zvbi-0.2.35-1.el7.x86_64
  - nothing provides libpng16.so.16()(64bit) needed by zvbi-0.2.35-9.el8.x86_64
  - nothing provides libpng16.so.16(PNG16_0)(64bit) needed by zvbi-0.2.35-9.el8.x86_64
 Problem 21: cannot install both libass-0.15.2-1.el8.x86_64 and libass-0.13.4-6.el7.x86_64
  - package ffmpeg-libs-3.4.11-1.el7.x86_64 requires libass.so.5()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package libass-0.13.4-6.el7.x86_64
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package ffmpeg-libs-3.4.11-1.el7.x86_64
 Problem 22: package vlc-core-1:3.0.17.2-1.el7.x86_64 requires libchromaprint.so.0()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install both libchromaprint-1.4.2-6.el8.x86_64 and libchromaprint-1.0-1.el7.x86_64
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package vlc-core-1:3.0.17.2-1.el7.x86_64
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package libchromaprint-1.0-1.el7.x86_64
 Problem 23: package vlc-1:3.0.17.2-1.el7.x86_64 requires libvlccore.so.9()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
  - package vlc-1:3.0.17.2-1.el7.x86_64 requires vlc-core(x86-64) = 1:3.0.17.2-1.el7, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package vlc-core-1:3.0.17.2-1.el7.x86_64 requires libixml.so.2()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
  - package vlc-core-1:3.0.17.2-1.el7.x86_64 requires libupnp.so.6()(64bit), but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install both libupnp-1.8.7-1.el8.x86_64 and libupnp-1.6.25-1.el7.x86_64
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package vlc-1:3.0.17.2-1.el7.x86_64
  - cannot install the best update candidate for package libupnp-1.6.25-1.el7.x86_64
================================================================================
 Package                    Arch    Version                       Repository
                                                                           Size
================================================================================
Skipping packages with conflicts:
(add '--best --allowerasing' to command line to force their upgrade):
 libass                     x86_64  0.15.2-1.el8                  epel    116 k
 libchromaprint             x86_64  1.4.2-6.el8                   epel     54 k
 libupnp                    x86_64  1.8.7-1.el8                   epel    116 k
Skipping packages with broken dependencies:
 aalib-libs                 x86_64  1.4.0-0.37.rc5.el8            epel     72 k
 elrepo-release             noarch  8.1-1.el8.elrepo              extras   14 k
 game-music-emu             x86_64  0.6.2-3.el8                   epel    155 k
 gperftools-libs            x86_64  1:2.7-9.el8                   epel    306 k
 jack-audio-connection-kit  x86_64  1.9.14-4.el8                  epel    523 k
 libaom                     x86_64  3.1.1-1.el8                   epel    1.7 M
 libcaca                    x86_64  0.99-0.59.beta20.el8          epel    225 k
 libcddb                    x86_64  1.3.2-30.el8                  epel     79 k
 libffado                   x86_64  2.4.4-2.el8                   epel    836 k
 libmfx                     x86_64  1.25-4.el8                    epel     36 k
 libmodplug                 x86_64  1:0.8.9.0-9.el8               epel    171 k
 libspatialaudio            x86_64  3.1-1.20200406gitd926a2e.el8  epel    884 k
 libssh2                    x86_64  1.9.0-5.el8                   epel    128 k
 libxml++                   x86_64  2.40.1-10.el8                 epel    102 k
 lirc-libs                  x86_64  0.10.0-19.el8                 epel    139 k
 rpmconf                    noarch  1.1.3-1.el8                   epel     27 k
 sox                        x86_64  14.4.2.0-29.el8               epel    434 k
 tcp_wrappers               x86_64  7.6-96.el8                    epel     87 k
 tcp_wrappers-libs          x86_64  7.6-96.el8                    epel     74 k
 zvbi                       x86_64  0.2.35-9.el8                  epel    424 k

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Skip  23 Packages

Nothing to do.
Complete!
```

I have already tried a lot suggestions on different forums by google but nothing has helped.

gnome update manager is failing as well. Please let me know if someone can help.

Comment: CentOS Linux 8 went End-of-Life on 2021-12-31, so your "upgrade to CentOS 8" was not really a future proof one.

Answer (score 3):

CentOS 8 is EOL: https://www.centos.org/centos-linux-eol/, as Rob said in the comments. You should migrate to [Rocky Linux](https://rockylinux.org/) or [AlmaLinux](https://almalinux.org/). They are 1:1 binary compatible with CentOS/RHEL.

You may also want to check out [ELevate](https://almalinux.org/elevate).

Comment: Installed AlmaLinux OS 8 and its running perfectly!